Why does chrome cause the current page to lose network connection when I open the network tab in inspector?
Whenever I go to a page and then open chrome inspector and go to the network tab, the page just displays the no internet message and it doesn't matter what page I go to, this happens. Refreshing doesn't do anything. I get the feeling when I open the tab it makes a request that breaks something but not sure how to fix it. I'm on version 131.0.6778.109 (Official Build) (arm64)
Below is screenshot


You see the Offline select box at the top of the panel (near the Disable cache checkbox)? That's a network throttling option that you did set. Unset it.
